# One-to-many relationship in Datastore and de-referencing in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a one to many relationship between two entities: the first one is a satellite and the second one is channel. The satellite form returns a satellite name which I want to appear in another HTML page, with the channel data where you can say that this channel is related to that satellite.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a good case for using the ReferenceProperty that is part of the Datastore  API of App Engine. Here's an idea to get you started:

```
class Satellite(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Channel(db.Model):
  satellite = db.ReferenceProperty(Satellite, collection_name='channels')
  freq = db.StringProperty()
```

With this you can assign channels like so:

```
my_sat = Satellite(name='SatCOM1')
my_sat.put()
Channel(satellite=my_sat,freq='28.1200Hz').put()
... #Add other channels ...
```

Then loop through channels for a given Satellite object:

```
for chan in my_sat.channels: 
  print 'Channel frequency: %s' % (chan.freq)
```

Anyway, this pretty much follows [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) that describes how to model entity relationships in App Engine. Hope this helps.