# How to loop through the one-to-many relations query results?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, one-to-many

I am confused about how to filter and display one-to-many relations.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488498/about-one-to-many-relationship-in-datastore-and-dereferncing-in-google-app-engine) and [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) ([and my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829736/how-to-filter-for-different-items)) I created a new ReferenceProperty `Tag` in addition to `Item`:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    ...
    title = db.StringProperty()
    url = db.StringProperty()
    image_source_url = db.StringProperty()
    ....

class Tag(db.Model):
    item = db.ReferenceProperty(Item, collection_name = "image_tags")
    tag = db.StringProperty()
```

I added two new items to `Tag` and the table now looks like this:

```
Key: ahNzYz...
ID: 269
Key Name:
item: ahNzYXJh...
      Item: id=268
tag: glam

Key: ahNxyz...
ID: 270
Key Name:
item: ahNzYXJh...
      Item: id=264
tag: casual
```

In my `SortFormHandler` I do this query and try to loop over the results:

```
class SortFormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):        
        query = Tag.all()
        query.filter("tag", "glam")

        for item in query.image_tags:
            self.response.out.write("""<a href="%s"><image src="%s" height="110">%s</a>""" % 
                                       (item.url, item.image_source_url, item.title)  )
```

This gives attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'image_tags'
```

I tried other combinations with no success. I would appreciate if someone can explain how this works so that I understand how to loop through the results.

Thanks.

**Update**

I tried Daniel Roseman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831787/how-to-loop-through-the-one-to-many-relations-query-results/4832058#4832058) like this:

```
        for tag in query:
            self.response.out.write("tag is: %s" % tag.tag)
            for item in tag.image_tags:
                self.response.out.write("""<a href="%s"><image src="%s" height="110">%s</a>""" % 
                                       (item.url, item.image_source_url, item.title)  )
```

but this gives

```
AttributeError: 'Tag' object has no attribute 'image_tags'
```

Any suggestions about how to fix this?

**Update 2**

I see that in `Tag` table the ID of the referenced item is stored under the column `item`. How do I get that ID? I tried

```
tag.item
```

in this line

```
        for tag in query:
            self.response.out.write("tag is: %s. ID is: %s" % (tag.tag, tag.item))
```

but this only returns the object:

```
tag is: glam. ID is: <__main__.Item object at 0x06875EB0>
```

**Update 3**

Ok, I figured how to get the key name of the referenced item:

```
        for tag in query:
            self.response.out.write(ID is: %s" % (tag.item.key()))
```

so

```
tag.item.key()
```

returns the key of the item that I need to use. How do I get the `url` and `title` etc of that item? And how do I display it?

**Update 4**

This appears to work (at least for 1 tag):

```
for tag in query:
    referenced_item_key = tag.item.key()
    item = Item.get(referenced_item_key)
    self.response.out.write("""<a href="%s"><image src="%s" height="110">%s</a>""" % 
                                       (item.url, item.image_source_url, item.title)  )
```

Note: Names are confusing this `item` refers to the the reference column in `Tag`:

```
    referenced_item_key = tag.item.key()
```

I should name this item something else:

```
    item = Item.get(referenced_item_key)
```

Comment: check the applied filter, you have 'query.filter("tag", "glam")', change it for 'query.filter("tag =", "glam")'

Comment: @eiefai: query works without "=" as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829138/how-to-make-the-argument-to-filter-a-variable/4829203#4829203 You can see in my Update 2 that tag is returned correctly as "glam".

Comment: `tag.item` is the item. You don't need to get its key, then fetch it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

You need two loops here. `query` is a list of Tag objects. Each object itself has a list of items. So you need to loop through `query`, then through each tag's items.

However, there is a second problem: the ReferenceProperty is the wrong way round. As I understand it, a ReferenceProperty is like a ForeignKey in normal Django: in other words, a one-to-many relationship where the model that defines the property is the 'one' side of the relationship. But you seem to want multiple Items for each Tag, which you then loop through: so you need to put the ReferenceProperty on the Item model.

Then, you can do your two loops:

```
 for tag in query:
     self.response.out.write('header for tag %s' % tag.tag)
     for item in tag.image_tags:
         self.response.out.write('detail for each item')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this by filling in the details for each item but I get an error. I'll an update.

Comment: This is wrong. Each tag plainly has a single item; no nested loops are required.